# How to generate all the WMS layers getGetFeatureInfoUrl details into iframe?

Tags: openlayers, popup, getfeatureinfo

With this code I am able to generate only the last layer GetFeatureInfo response only, I am able to display all the layer URLs but how am I able to show all the layers details in the iframes (number of WMS layers = number of iframes).

Here I have one base layer and 3 layers so I am expecting 3 individual iframes as overlays on the map.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/css/ol.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.5.0/ol.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/build/ol.js"> </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>        
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup"> <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
<a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer">X</a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
closer.onclick = function() {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

var layers = [
new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
   url: 'http://ndem.nrsc.gov.in/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'ndem50k:stateadmin50census2011'}
        })
      }),

 new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8089/geoserver/manjula/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'manjula:prakasam'}
         })
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8089/geoserver/manjula/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'manjula:krishna'}
         })
      }),

      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8089/geoserver/manjula/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'manjula:guntur'}
         })
  })

];
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var popup = new ol.Overlay( /** @type {olx.OverlayOptions} */ ({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
    }
}));
var mapcenter = [79.60,23.44];
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    overlays: [popup],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
               center: mapcenter,
               zoom: 5,
               extent: [66.2329, 7.68083, 98.2223, 39.03874],
               maxZoom:16,
               minZoom: 4,
    })
});

map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
//alert();
 content.innerHTML = "";

    var displayedLayers = [];
    var responses = 0;
 var layersCollection = map.getLayers();
// alert(layersCollection.a.length-1);
 //alert("0"+ layersCollection.item(0).getSource());
 for (i = 1; i <= ((layersCollection.a.length-1)); i++)
{ //Loops through all layers excluding baselayer at index 0 and gets their URL
alert();
    var layerID = layersCollection.item(i);
    var url = layerID.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl( evt.coordinate,map.getView().getResolution(), 'EPSG:4326',{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/plain'});
    alert(url);
    popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    content.innerHTML = 
    '<iframe  src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    //document.content.appendChild("<iframe></iframe>");
    container.style.display = 'block';

}

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really want to query each layer individually?  GetFeatureInfo request allows you to query multiple layers in one go.

Comment: @nnmtoken how can you populate a single iframe with attributes from multliple layers returned by getFeatureInfo?